# How to specify containers id to apache camel's containerstart operation?

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I'm trying to use Spring Boot + Apache Camel + Kafka in order to subscribe to some topic, then start some dockers containers and wait for it, but once I added the line:
`to(docker:contianerstart?host...)` then I'm getting the next exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Container ID must be specified must be specified
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:151) ~[camel-util-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.docker.producer.DockerProducer.executeStartContainerRequest(DockerProducer.java:1045) ~[camel-docker-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.docker.producer.DockerProducer.process(DockerProducer.java:163) ~[camel-docker-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66) ~[camel-support-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:169) ~[camel-core-processor-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:395) ~[camel-core-processor-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147) ~[camel-core-processor-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:312) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41) ~[camel-support-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$KafkaFetchRecords.doRun(KafkaConsumer.java:357) ~[camel-kafka-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$KafkaFetchRecords.run(KafkaConsumer.java:222) ~[camel-kafka-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]

2022-10-24 17:02:24.101  WARN 251133 --- [new-crew-files]] o.a.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer  : Error during processing. Exchange[F02B0892689E52A-0000000000000000]. Caused by: [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Container ID must be specified must be specified]

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Container ID must be specified must be specified
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:151) ~[camel-util-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.docker.producer.DockerProducer.executeStartContainerRequest(DockerProducer.java:1045) ~[camel-docker-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.docker.producer.DockerProducer.process(DockerProducer.java:163) ~[camel-docker-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66) ~[camel-support-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:169) ~[camel-core-processor-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:395) ~[camel-core-processor-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147) ~[camel-core-processor-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:312) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41) ~[camel-support-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$KafkaFetchRecords.doRun(KafkaConsumer.java:357) ~[camel-kafka-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$KafkaFetchRecords.run(KafkaConsumer.java:222) ~[camel-kafka-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Code is below. How to pass the container ID over here?

```
from("kafka:new-files?brokers=localhost:9092")
    .setProperty("proc_vers", simple(procVers()))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_REPOSITORY, simple("parser"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_TAG, simple("latest")) 
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_IMAGE_ID, simple("efded01f5f75"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_IMAGE, simple("parser:latest"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_NAME, exchangeProperty("proc_vers"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_ENV, () -> new String []{
                        "MODE=xxx", "PARSER_CLIENT=xxx",
                        "PATHS=/home/xxx/xxx"  })
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_BINDS, simple("/home/xxx:/xxx"))
    .to("docker:containercreate?host=/var/run/docker.sock")
    .to("docker:containerstart?host=/var/run/docker.sock?parameters=")
    .log("container started")
    .log("container end");
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that the operation `containercreate` returns a response of type [`com.github.dockerjava.api.command.CreateContainerResponse`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.github.docker-java/docker-java/3.0.14/com/github/dockerjava/api/command/CreateContainerResponse.html), the id can be retrieved from [its getter](https://javadoc.io/static/com.github.docker-java/docker-java/3.0.14/com/github/dockerjava/api/command/CreateContainerResponse.html#getId--) so you just need to set the Camel header corresponding to the id of the container before calling the `containerstart` operation as next:

```
    ...
    .to("docker:containercreate")
    // Calls getId on the body of the message that is of type 
    // CreateContainerResponse and uses the result as container id
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_CONTAINER_ID, simple("${body.id}"))
    .to("docker:containerstart")
    ...
```